# Why does this TypeScript program compile?

Tags: typescript

Let's start with an apology for the overly generic question, but I am wrecking my head how to narrow it down due to lack of understanding of what's happening here, so will adjust based on comments / answers.

I have created a sample program on [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.2#code/C4TwDgpgBAyhzAJYDsDmBnKBeKBvKA5AIYEBcUARgPZUA2ERyA3IRWVOsAE4qpQC%20AKEEAzAK7IAxkirIO8OAl4AeANJQIAD2ARkAE0wBrCCCojY8JGnQA%20ABRhyqgDRQAbuUVWMAbVUBdAEpyNypEPTwhQQB6aPlgL147YgJXAEYABgzAqFioVBo9FkRgKBEiRFp0QXQFSySU124xCECWPIKqIqhJKgBbMEqIatEJaURZSi4GQ0VEtDtDcmNTc3mMVw9KGnpGYPcwiNxBKHj1xc22wSiKaaJZuqUFgjYmrha23LiKIm6Snv6g3o6AAhEA) that should not compile but does (using latest version of TypeScript, v4.5.2 as of this writing.) I am trying to understand why this compiles in order to understand what other bad programs might sneak past the type checker and go undetected. Here is [another version of the program](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.2#code/C4TwDgpgBAyhzAJYDsDmBnKBeKBvKAhgFxQBGA9uQDYQHIDcUZJ6wATiqlAL4BQvAMwCuyAMZJyyKOnhwEnADwBpKBAAewCMgAmmANYQQ5AbHhI06AHwAKdCTnmMAGihgSSlwDd7ZzugDaSgC6AJQ%208hZ4vExs8EJsUrgAdCnoLv5gQSSefHy8opKs0r4W4Y6YOLjEUOxCEC6kJADkApRN3PT8APRdNQAWiJikVOSielAFALZgiDSYvQIEs5jA5BPk07PQBJjqkOIQ2ry40VA9xcAOnLYlzlBNBE0uAIwADK8hZ72olNqMiMAoItlqcZJdbjcIncHk8amw6iFGOcfuQ-utNnNeHlhGIJFJSLECHo5Fc0LYyn4XHoSAYjCZSXdvGRKDQ6GFTFDMCcYnEEhcGbYqV5EVjur1gANMOg%20uQhFRtFBkORAX0CJ5oFMZjQFTt7qQmtIZXKFaRoMYauBoE1WBw0E1jqcCsgikIwNoCJptAyKmRCcTZBCweUXE19S5ahBEV8yAQ0QD0VqIOgAISOwrUCBJEaoayu92e71JUjhy3mvMew6F0ghLFAA) that shows the problem at runtime. Are there any options I have overlooked or anything I can do to have this program not type check?

For convenience, I inline the program in question here as well:

```
type Settings = { 'a': boolean; 'b': string }

function setSetting<K extends keyof Settings>(p: K, v: Settings[K]): void {}

// setSetting('a', 100) // good; it fails
setSetting('a', true); // good; compiles

function breakSetSetting(k: keyof Settings, v: boolean): void {
  setSetting(k, v);
}

breakSetSetting('b', true); // bad; it compiles!
```

Update: As per comment by @crashmstr using generics for `breakSettings` [makes the program not compile](http://C4TwDgpgBAyhzAJYDsDmBnKBeKBvKA5AIYEBcUARgPZUA2ERyA3IRWVOsAE4qpQC+AKEEAzAK7IAxkirIO8OAl4AeANJQIAD2ARkAE0wBrCCCojY8JGnQA+ABRhyqgDRQAbuUVWMAbVUBdAEpyNypEPTwhQQB6aPlgL147YgJXAEYABgzAqFioVBo9FkRgKBEiRFp0QXQFSySU124xCECWPIKqIqhJKgBbMEqIatEJaURZSi4GQ0VEtDUNbV0DKGNTc3mMe0MnVw9KGnpGYPcwiNxBKHittR39tsEoimmiWbqlNGS2Jq4WttycQoRG6JR6-UG9HQAEIgA), however, it's still unclear to me why it was allowed to compile before.

Comment: If you use the same generics signature in the breakSetSetting, then you *do* get a compiler error there that you cannot just pass in a boolean `v`. As it is, the most the compiler knows is that the call into `setSetting` there is a `string | bool` for the second parameter and the `v` does "work" for that.

Comment: @crashmstr [yup](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.2#code/C4TwDgpgBAyhzAJYDsDmBnKBeKBvKA5AIYEBcUARgPZUA2ERyA3IRWVOsAE4qpQC+AKEEAzAK7IAxkirIO8OAl4AeANJQIAD2ARkAE0wBrCCCojY8JGnQA+ABRhyqgDRQAbuUVWMAbVUBdAEpyNypEPTwhQQB6aPlgL147YgJXAEYABgzAqFioVBo9FkRgKBEiRFp0QXQFSySU124xCECWPIKqIqhJKgBbMEqIatEJaURZSi4GQ0VEtDUNbV0DKGNTc3mMe0MnVw8LJWs-IJCwiNxBKHitu0N9tsEoimmiWbqj1GS2Jq4WttycQoRG6JR6-UG9HQAEJBEA). You should probably write that as an answer.

Comment: Thanks, I have updated the question, however, I am still not sure why the previous program managed to compile at all

Answer (score 3):

When you define `K`, you are defining it to be `'a' | 'b'` (which is `keyof K`). This means that `v` would be `Settings['a' | 'b']` which evaluates to `boolean | string`. Now when your `breakSetSetting` passes a `boolean` to `setSetting`, `boolean` is in the scope of `boolean | string`, making the compiler pass.

Comment: I think I am getting there, however, I do not understand why this is allowed to compile still. So to recap, my understanding of the problem is that when `K` is selected as a union, `Settings[K]` is a union as well and since unions are not ordered the actual values in those unions could mismatch.

Edit: I can see how the first program compiles now. I wonder if the second version of the program I linked (that features the problem at runtime) is just implemented problematically using `{...s, [p]: v}`. Maybe there's a safer way to do that part?